# LLDB manual/documentation

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, prompt, lldb

I would like to understand a bit better how to debug my iOS code with LLDB. I often see my colleagues debugging using the prompt, to see for instance the value of variables and so on. Where can I find some documentation as to how to use the LLDB debugger on command line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cant you ask your colleagues :)?

Comment: I did, the answer was: google here and there...

Comment: if you want to impress your colleagues, [edit breakpoints](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/setting_breakpoint_actions_and_options.html) to perform an action (including lldb commands) without stoping the program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html) is the best resource for LLDB since it is the official tutorial.

Comment: Thanks.
I forgot to mention that I had looked at that website, however the 'documentation' section is empty. There is something on the homepage, however there the authors seem to focus on things such as attaching processes (to the debugger) and the likes, which is now what you'd be doing in XCode...

Answer (score 5):

You may want to watch the Apple WWDC session video on lldb from June, if you have access to those.  https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/   Session title was "Debugging with LLDB", the description of the session is

> LLDB is the next-generation debugger for OS X and iOS. Get an introduction to using LLDB via the console interface and within Xcode's graphical debugger. The team that created LLDB will demonstrate the latest features and improvements, helping you track down bugs more efficiently than ever before.

Answer (score 2):

This GDB->LLDB chart may help, even if you are not familiar with GDB:

http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [Apple finally wrote LLDB documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/Introduction.html) around Sep 2013.

I'm adding this answer because this question is a top hit in my searches, and Apple usually does a good job with docs (when they finally get around to it).